# Find how close N is to V

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of a program.

I've looked at the accuracy formula and it looks like this:

```
e_value = 400
t_value = 1000

accuracy = ((t_value - e_value)/t_value) * 100
```

And this works as expected (40%).

What if `e_value` is much bigger than the t_value though?

In my case for example, my `e_value` is `18` while the `t_value` is `2`.

The accuracy should (?) be a very low number as `18` is 9 times `2`, but the number we get if we plug in the numbers is `-800%` which doesn't really seem right (and also, it's not really what I'm after, I want a number between 0-100%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide what the percentage is for.  If e_value is a number of tests passed and t_value is the number of tests given, you always have t_value greater and there is no problem.  If you are just checking one computed number against the other you can.  One choice is to make the denominator the greater of e_value or t_value, then subtract from $1$ when you use e-value.  That will duly get your values in the $0-100\%$ range.  In the case you cite, you would do $1-\frac {18-2}{18}\approx 0.11$, then multiply by $100\%$ to get $11\%$.  Whether this conveys useful information is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You get $40\%$ not $60\%$ in the first case.  You are calculating the error as a perfect of the true value.  In the second case, the error is $-16$ which is $-800\%$ of the true value.  It is what it is.